# Can't set output to 4k 60hz on Pi 4

Tags: display, output, pi-4

What I've tried:

**Setting "4Kp60 HDMI"**

I did this in the GUI config application and rebooted. Also tried disabling it and then enabling it in the config.txt and rebooted.

**Installing updates**

My initial install I didn't install updates during setup. After having issues I installed updates but no luck. I tried another, fresh install, and installed updates during setup but again, no luck.

**Setting hdmi_group and hdmi_mode**

I tried group 2 and mode 77 for 1600p at 60hz. I also tried hdmi_force_mode after that didn't work but it stayed to what I set it at previously (either 4k@30 or 1080@60).

**Setting the resolution**

After each attempt, I tried setting the resolution with both xrandr and arandr - I know it wouldn't make a difference but just in case...

xrandr gives me this output:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 7680 x 7680
HDMI-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 1872mm x 1053mm
   3840x2160     30.00 +  30.00    25.00    25.00    24.00    24.00    29.97    23.98  
   4096x2160     30.00    25.00    24.00    24.00    29.97    23.98  
   1920x1080     60.00*   60.00    50.00    59.94    30.00    25.00    24.00    29.97    23.98  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1366x768      59.79  
   1280x800      59.91  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08
```

**Display**: Samsung UE40NU7120

I believe the display might be the problem as it's a TV. But it's a fairly recent one and handles 4k@60 from my PC.

**HDMI cable**: https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B014I8TVLI/ref=twister_B01AM5SOUK?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1

I don't have another micro HDMI so I can't test that. This claims to support 4k@60hz though. I've tried both ports on the pi too.

I've seen a couple of posts on other sites about this with no fix. It's hard to search for though as every link is discussing the feature.

**Update**

I've tried this on other 4k displays and it works fine at 60hz. It appears to be a problem with this particular display.

**Update 2**

Semi-related for people that might come across this looking for answers, I've no longer got the Pi 4, but I had a similar issue with my PC with an RX 580 GPU and the same display. This [Ask Ubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/257728/force-refresh-rate) seems to have resolved it for me. As I said though, no Pi 4, so I can't test it there.

Comment: I hope you find the solution, but in case for other web user I have succefully put the pi4 to 4K 60Hz doing this : https://imgur.com/a/W9fTcl2 have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

There is a setting for the particular type of HDMI in the Samsung TV:

```
Settings>General>External Device Manager>Input settings Plus
```

It is possible to select the full range of HDMI options.

Answer (score 0):

On Samsung Series 6 TV, no matter what I did, the 60hz wasn't working. Other devices (Fire TV 4k, Nvidia shield TV)  don't have this issue. So, I first plugged in Nvidia Shield TV and set the 4k resolution at 60Hz then unplugged it and plugged in Raspberry pi in off state and started it. Now it shows 4k 60p. Hope this helps.